# When should these helping verbs be used after the word 'bodyguard'?

Tags: verbs

The royal bodyguard has/have deserted en route.
In the sentence, which helping verb, has or have, should be used.

Comment: Why do you think that you should use "have". Would tell us what do you think yourself?

Comment: The word 'bodyguard' has plural meaning, I think.

Answer (score 1):

The word *bodyguard* can indicate an individual or a military unit, and it is not clear how you are using it in your example. If you mean a military unit, then you should put:

> The royal bodyguard has deserted en route.

However, since desertion is basically an individual act, it might be better to put:

> The royal bodyguards have deserted en route.

It all depends on whether they acted individually or together (under command of their officers).

Comment: The quirk here is that, mostly in BrE, nouns for groups of people are inherently plural and take the plural form of the verb -- for example "the crowd are" instead of "the crowd is".  So the answer depends on whether we're talking BrE or AmE -- in BrE "the royal bodyguard have" ought to be fine if they all deserted as a group.  If it was a solo act then the one bodyguard "*has* deserted".  [Further reading](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2011/09/agreement-over-collective-nouns/)

Answer (score 1):

The noun "bodyguard" is singular. "Has" is the singular verb.

> The royal bodyguard has deserted...

This is correct whether the bodyguard is an individual or a collective noun (which is still singular) for a group of bodyguards.

"Have" is correct for a plural:

> The royal bodyguards have deserted...